# How do I make colours consistent between different programs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, corel-draw, color-profile

Ever since Windows 10 big update about a week a ago I am having some issues with colour between different programs, namely Photoshop (CS6) and Corel Draw (X7). (Illustrator is the same as Photoshop)

As seen in the picture below the 50% grey is totally off in both pictures (documents are CMYK - Photoshop on the left, Corel Draw on the right).

[image]

I have tried playing with every setting in Corel Draw but it just does not seem to be doing anything to the Black - Grey - White. The colours like Cyan, Magenta Yellow Green etc all seem to ok in both the RGB and CMYK.

I am having most trouble with CMYK Black - Grey - White.

These are the settings for the two programs.

Corel - European Default (tried to change CMYK to FOGRA27 still nothing changed)

[image]

Photshop - European Default

[image]

I've tried all the different settings, colour engine, preserve pure black etc, as well as changing the default presets but nothing seems to change in the Black - Grey - White.

Is there a way to make sure the different programs display colours consistently or near consistent?

Note 1: Viewing the artwork created in Corel Draw on another screen shows the colours to be correct.

Note 2: Taking a 50% grey image exported from Photoshop into Corel Draw shows the grey wrong. It shows it as it is in the first image.

Comment: what proof setup you have set in photoshop? Is your monitor calibrated? If yes on what profile?

Comment: Working CMYK in both softwares. The monitors have not been calibrated with any tools. however the windows Colour Management has it set as sRGB IEC61966-2.1

Comment: Tty turning BPC (black point compensation) off.

Comment: it seems that after restarting the computer this morning, with the same settings above has worked. The colours are now consistent between both programs.